# SQL Server 2019 - Ordering in sub select

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

In my database I have a Tracking Codes table as a child of a single Employment table. Along with other data, I am trying to return all of the Tracking Codes in a comma separated string so there will only be one row per Employment. However, I want this string sorted by the Tracking Code Order table that will give a numerical order depending on the Tracking Code.

My Tracking Code Tables look like this:

TrackingCodeOrder Table

| Name | Order |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

TrackingCode Table

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 321 | B |
| 159 | C |

The current code I am using is:

```
(
    select top(1) string_agg(tc.TrackingCode, ',') 
    from TrackingCode as tc 
    left join TrackingCodeOrder tco on tco.Name = tc.TrackingCode
    where etc.Employment_id = e.id
    group by tco.Order
    order by tco.Order asc
) as 'TrackingCodeId'

from employee e
```

When I attempt to do it with this code, it runs, but I do not get all of my tracking codes returned. Some have 2 but will only return 1, others will have 9 but only return 4. If I remove the top(1), group by, and order by, I will see all the codes returned correctly, but not in the expected order. I have also attempted using `top 100 percent`. But the sub select will return more than one item.

Is there another way that I can sort in this sub select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided your database compatibility^ is set to an appropriate level, then you need to use the specific order clause for STRING_AGG

```
STRING_AGG(tc.TrackingCode, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tco.Order ASC)
```

Read more at the official MS docs for SQL, STRING_AGG() function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

^ Note that the STRING_AGG() function is firstly compatible with certain versions of SQL Server, but the WITHIN GROUP clause will only be supported if the specific database you are querying against is set at an appropriate compatibility level.  If your database compatibility level is too low, then a query with STRING_AGG() - without the WITHIN GROUP clause - may return a result successfully, but adding the WITHIN GROUP clause will then cause a syntax error.

Comment: This works! I have now learned that string_agg has an optional order clause. Thank you Craig!